# Are there something called wifi-enabled external storage disks?

Tags: wireless-networking, external-hard-drive, home-networking, storage, portable-harddrive

I have 2 laptops at my home and one external disk. I have a requirement (more out of curiosity on how to achieve it than a real need):

I have set-up basic adhoc home network where one laptop accesses internet by usb data card and other shares the internet. Now I want to move one step further and attach an external storage disk to the network such that both the laptops can simultaneously access the disk?

How can I achieve this?

Is there a way to share one full drive from a computer with the network by say right clicking on the drive and share it in read-write mode like we share any other folder in LAN..

or is there a way to use a wireless router in the network and connect this external usb storage disk to a router port (if any)..

are there any network switches used for this purpose?

Please give some clue!

Comment: Seagate has a new wireless storage product...http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/external/external-hard-drive/goflex-satellite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a NAS drive,  network attached storage,  some more expensive all in one Wireless Routers, include methods for attaching a normal external hard drive using USB,  but more commonly you purchase an external drive with the ethernet port built in,  I have not seen many with Wifi,  but the most common way to use them is wired to the router/switch.

http://www.techradar.com/news/networking/routers-storage/best-nas-drive-8-of-the-best-on-test-721118
The review above is from last here, but should provide you with more information on how they work.